# how to change video codec when using the vlcplayer dart package?

Tags: flutter

I m working on a flutter app that monitors the live video feed of IP cameras , my vlcplayer controller in working fine , intiliazed and playing videos , however when i tried to implement a recording feature , the controller will not record and the isRecording boolean is always false , i suspect it s a codec issue , and i didn t know how to change it , if you have another suggestion to why the recording doesn t work , please let me know.

I tried changing it inside the VLcPlayerOptions but i didn t find it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.